# "I found her sit on the table" ungrammatical?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

My online English teacher marked my answer for a practice question, the title, as wrong. And it revised that into ***sitting*** instead of ***sit***. But could I just use that sentence, as it is, conveying the meaning that "she was seen in the act of sitting down"? I meant (sorry for my short English skill) she definitely started to sit, however her butt was not yet completely landed on the table, or just landed. Or, simply, does the verb ***Find*** not go well together with something in progress?

Comment: I found her taking a seat.    It doesn't have to do with actions in progress.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your teacher is right.

To say what you are trying to convey, you could use one of these:

> I **saw** her sit on the table.
>   I **watched** her sit on the table.

But *found* doesn't work; *found* means you saw someone in a certain state, not in a process.

Although you could say:

> I found her **in the act of sitting**.

I probably would have corrected your sentence the same way your teacher did.

Comment: How about "I found her sitting on the table."?

Comment: @马化腾 - "I found her sitting on the table" would work, but most would probably assume that meant she was already seated, and not in the act of seating herself.